# TeamViewer - Suspicious Behavior - Maybe hacked?

Tags: teamviewer

recently I found a few times when I came back to my computer after a break, that the TeamViewer startup window was opened!
Is this normal behavior? Or should I suspect that someone hacked into my computer using Teamviewer, or at least tried to?
I looked into the log files, and I do see action during the time that I wasnt near my computer, but I dont know what anything means.

If anyone has a clue, I'd appreciate hearing it.

Thanks,
David

Comment: TeamViewer suffered a [security breach](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/06/teamviewer-users-are-being-hacked-in-bulk-and-we-still-dont-know-how/) a couple months ago. You should uninstall it. It may not be a bad idea to monitor your credit card usage as well and change your passwords. Does TeamViewrer have connection logs in the client? Maybe check them out and see if a connection was made.

Comment: @Chris, thanks. I've heard of that breach and I had it closed for a while. Then I started using it again.... As I mentioned, there is a log but I can't really understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to change your **ID** and **Password**.

And when they do not close it.

> Connection > Exit TeamViewer

On page TeamViewer **Extras** menu and the selection of the **Open log file**.
Explorer opens.
Open the file and check the **connections.txt** that are set up along time.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt see the connections.txt file before - I opened it and see that there were no incoming connections today - That's calming news... By the way, you suggest changing both ID and Password?

Comment: I'd say yes. ....